# Creating a subselection with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute

I want to do the following:

from a point layer's table,

1) grab all GEBID (an attribute) and create a list(1) with unique GEBIDs

2) iterate through the list(1) in a loop:

2a) stuff all features with matching GEBIDs into a temporary list(2)

2b) pick the entry with the largest Area (another attribute)

2c) write the entry into a third list(3)

3) use the third list(3) to select the features
 
The resulting selection should be like the red text:

[image]

Here's my code so far, but I'm stumped at 2b)..

```
import arcpy

IDList = []
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("A_Gebauede_Dachform_F2P")

for row in rows: 
    IDList.append(row.getValue("GEBID"))

IDSet = set(IDList)
IDSetList = list(IDSet)

for i in range(len(IDSetList)):
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("A_Gebauede_Dachform_F2P","GEBID = '"+IDSetList[i]+"'")
    ???
```

Comment: You can loop over `rows`, appending the values from `Area` to a new list and then use `max()` to get the highest and then another loop. Or, just use [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) with a MAX operator on `Area` and case field on `GEBID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just paste the code below into your ArcMap Python console window for it to work, unless you are using a geodatabase in which case you'll need to change the "uniqueIdFieldName" to match your input table's unique id field (like OBJECTID).

Like @dslamb said, you will need a field name for a "unique id" in your table.

If one "group" has more than one record that has the same "max value", this code will select both those records with the max value since they are technically the "maximum".

Make sure to set the input variables to match the layers and field names accordingly.

```
import arcpy

#this will become a list of unique ids you will select at the end
selectionList = []

##set your important variables here:
layerName = "A_Gebauede_Dachform_F2P"
uniqueIdFieldName = "FID" #FID for shapefiles, OBJECTID for geodatabases
groupFieldName = "GEBID"
valueFieldName = "AREA"

#your code is here, with some variable modification
IDList = []
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(layerName)

for row in rows: 
    IDList.append(row.getValue(groupFieldName))

IDSet = set(IDList)
IDSetList = list(IDSet)

#this searches through your layer for the max areas, and builds a list of unique IDs to select on
for i in range(len(IDSetList)):
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("my_source","GEBID = '" + IDSetList[i] + "'")
    row = cursor.next()
    iddb = dict() #initialize your unique id and value dictionary for the group
    while row: #this builds the unique id and value dictionary 
        iddb[row.getValue(uniqueIdFieldName)] = row.getValue(valueFieldName)
        row = cursor.next()
    maxVal = iddb[max(iddb, key=iddb.get)] #load the maximum value for the current group
    #get all ids that match this maximum value
    for id, measure in iddb.iteritems():
        if measure == maxVal:
            selectionList.append(int(id)) 

#build the selection expression
expression = uniqueIdFieldName + ' IN (' + ','.join(map(str, selectionList)) + ')'

#select the records for each 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management( layerName,"NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked on a small data sample. I'm wondering why it's so slow, though. I'm running the script (from a toolbox) on a ~65k point layer and it does roughly 5500 records per hour. Also strange: the script throws a proper error (some GEBIDs were missing, so the selection failed) while using a small set, but simply fails with no stated reason on a large set.

Comment: Sorry about the performance, but unless I have the data I can't really troubleshoot/debug/optimize. Have you tried it with a "clean" subset of data, one that doesn't have missing GEBIDs? How long does it take to do a set of only 500 records? 2000? Are you watching your operating systems usage of memory? Maybe this script is maxing out RAM?

Comment: Yes, I used a clean copy of the proper datasets. Didn't run into any hardware issues, however the performance varies on another machine with the same hardware, so I guess this had nothing to do with the script itself. This wasn't urgent so I just let the script do its thing on the side - good enough for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a unique id for each row to distinguish between GEBID's and their area. You could use FID, but this is subject to change when a featureclass is edited (assuming this is a featureclass and not a table of some sort).

Assuming you have this unique row ID. You could do something like this.

```
import arcpy
gebids = {}

#using searchcursor from the da module for faster processing
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("A_Gebauede_Dachform_F2P",["SOMEROWID","GEBID","AREA"]) as sc:
    for row in sc:
        if row[1] in gebids.keys():
            if row[2] > gebids[row[1]][0]:
                gebids[row[1]]=[row[2],row[0]] #dictionary with key set to gebid, and value is set to a list of area and row id
        else:
            gebids[row[1]]=[row[2],row[0]]

rowids = ["'%s'"%v[1] for k,v in gebids.iteritems()] #pull out the ids

queryStr = "SOMEROWID in (%s)"%",".join(rowids) #you can use the IN keyword to find values in a list
print queryStr #if you want to see what it is

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("A_Gebauede_Dachform_F2P",["SOMEROWID","GEBID","AREA"],where_clause=queryStr) as sc:
   for row in sc:
      pass #do something with the selection
```

The code above uses the GEBID as a key in a dictionaries. Keys have to be unique, so this will store uniqe GEBID. The value is set as a list where the first index is the area and second index is the unique row id.

I used a list comprehension to pull out the unique row id, and convert it to s string surrounded by '' to be used in the query. I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with the second search cursor. You could also use SelectByAttribute and the query string.